# Event 100, System.ServiceModel.Activation 4.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Over the last few weeks I've seen errors appearing in the windows logs quoting the following:

```
The description for Event ID 100 from source System.ServiceModel.Activation 4.0.0.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

System.InvalidOperationException: Etw registration failed with error code e.
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsEventProvider..ctor(Guid providerGuid)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwProvider..ctor(Guid id)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace.CreateEtwProvider(Guid etwProviderId)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..ctor(String traceSourceName, Guid etwProviderId)
w3wp
1540
```

This is a windows server 2008, running sites under IIS and .NET 4

These errors are happening every 30 seconds or so now, and I have no idea where they are originating from.

All of the sites are running under the default ASP.NET v4.0 application pool.

Any one else had this error before?

I don't really want to do anything like a .NET repair unless I have to, as this is a live server and the sites on it are in use.

Thanks for any help.